# Retrieve value using index number jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this below codes all three DIV have same class name what i am trying to do is access/retrieve the second DIV value by using jquery index number the value of second DIV is 3.21, i tried to use this code to retrieve `div.OddVal.index(2)` with no luck any idea guys where i am wrong?

```
<div class="ThreeWayCol OddsCol1">
   <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.37</div>
   <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.21</div>
   <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">2.07</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've tagged the question with **jQuery**, so I believe that you are looking for [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```js
console.log($('.OddVal').eq(1).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.37</div>

<div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.21</div>

<div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">2.07</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ori Drori, This is what i was looking for, Be Blessed.

Comment: Live long and prosper :)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways `eq` has been explained in the other answers so I won't be adding that.
I've used `n:th` selector and `each` loop

```js
$(".OddVal").each(function(index) {
  if (index === 1) {
    console.log("Each loop result " + $(this).text());
  }
});
console.log("nth slector result " + $(".OddVal:nth-child(2)").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ThreeWayCol OddsCol1">

  <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.37</div>

  <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.21</div>

  <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">2.07</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ishan Mahjan this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `eq()` method to get the value of specified index as

```
var val = $('.OddVal').eq(your_index_no_here).text();// must be numeric as 1,2,3
alert(val);
```

You can get the documention [JQuery eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Thanks @RAUSHAN KUMAR this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can see working example here:

Demo here: https://jsbin.com/rubapoz/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function() {
        var index = $("#txtIndex").val();
        alert($('.ThreeWayCol .OddVal').eq(index).text());
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ThreeWayCol OddsCol1">
    <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.37</div>
    <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">3.21</div>
    <div class="OddVal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-repeat="sel in event._matchMarket.selections" ng-model="sel" ng-class="{'Sel': oddSelections[event.id].sels[sel.id]}" ng-click="selectOdd(event,event._matchMarket,sel)">2.07</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter index like: 0,1" id="txtIndex" />
  <input type="button" value="Get Value" id="btn" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very helpful, much appreciate @CKG

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://api.jquery.com/get/

The .get() method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object. If the value of index is out of bounds — less than the negative number of elements or equal to or greater than the number of elements — it returns undefined. Consider a simple unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
</ul>
```

With an index specified, .get( index ) retrieves a single element:

```
console.log( $( "li" ).get( 0 ) );
```

Since the index is zero-based, the first list item is returned:

```
<li id="foo">
```